# Netty compilation throws checkstyle error on windows

Tags: maven, netty, checkstyle

I did a git clone from github `git://github.com/netty/netty.git` followed by `mvn clean install`. However I got the following errors from `maven checkstyle plugin`

```
C:\git\netty\common\src\main\java\io\netty\util\UniqueName.java:106: Line matches the illegal pattern '\r'.
C:\git\netty\common\src\main\java\io\netty\util\UniqueName.java:107: Line matches the illegal pattern '\r'.
C:\git\netty\common\src\main\java\io\netty\util\UniqueName.java:108: Line matches the illegal pattern '\r'.
C:\git\netty\common\src\main\java\io\netty\util\UniqueName.java:109: Line matches the illegal pattern '\r'.
....
Audit done.
```

I use a windows 7 machine with `java version "1.7.0_06"`. How do prevent these errors and get a good compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to configure git to use lf only: https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings#platform-windows

Comment: Shouldn't the .gitattributes file for Netty also be checked in to git in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You may just edit these files and replace `\r` to `\n`.

Or if you want just compile project and ignore all messages from checkstyle, I suggest to set properties `failsOnError` and `failOnViolation` to `false` (in code: https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/pom.xml#L311) In this case checkstyle still will check the sources, but will not fail it when find something.